# Sony Xperia AOSP 8.0 system.img wrong size

Tags: android, android-source, sony, sony-xperia

I am having some trouble flashing my Sony Xperia X with the AOSP Android 8.0 build from Sony.

The system image files have been built, but I am unable to flash the `system.img` file to my phone.

I am using the following, command, as stated in Sony's documentation:

```
fastboot –S 256M flash system out/target/product/<device>/system.img
```

Which results in the following error:

```
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.033s]
sending sparse 'system' 1/5 (261911 KB)...
OKAY [  8.575s]
writing 'system' 1/5...
FAILED (remote: size too large)
finished. total time: 8.611s
```

It seems to me that the `system.img` file have been built with the wrong size.

`BoardConfig.mk` states that the following:

```
BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 7843348480
```

My `system.img` file has the following size:

```
.............  1086617000 okt.   4 22:35 system.img
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Attempted flashing with an outdated version of the bootloader. Installing the latest bootloader fixes the problem.